# Find documents following the document in MongoDB capped collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a [MongoDB capped collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/).

Given an `_id` of an object in that collection, I need to get the next N items in the [$natural](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) order. I would assume that should be easy for the database since in a capped collection the documents I assume just follow each other in the storage engine.

I tried doing this query:

```
.find({"_id": {$gt: objectId}}).sort({"$natural": 1}).limit(10)
```

but it does a collection scan and is therefore very slow.

I also tried getting a cursor and getting next item, but that fails too:

```
> cursor = db.collectionName.find({_id: ObjectId('64dea9f339ddcd63c0e9f7cb')})
> cursor.next()
MongoCursorExhaustedError: Cursor is exhausted
```

How do I quickly get documents that follow a certain document in a capped collection in MongoDB?

P.S. I understand I can achieve this goal by adding another field like timestamp and using an index on it, but I was wondering if I can achieve this just by using `_id` and `$natural` order.

Comment: Simply try `sort({_id: 1})`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit correct me if I am wrong, but I think that might return results _not_ in the order of insertion. Because it may be generated by different machines, and because it only has a resolution of one second. [MongoDB documentation as a source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the generated `_id` field, i.e. `sort({_id: 1})`

An `ObjectId` is a 12-byte Field of BSON type

- The first 4 bytes representing the Unix Timestamp of the document (resolution of second)
- The next 3 bytes are the machine Id on which the MongoDB server is running.
- The next 2 bytes are of process Id
- The last Field is 3 bytes used for **increment** the ObjectId.

3 Bytes are 24 Bits, unless you insert more than 1.6 Million documents per second or restart the `mongod` process, the order of `_id` should be equal to the order of inserts.

It should be also fine for a replicaSet or Sharded Cluster because in case the PRIMARY server switches, you pass at least one second.